# How to write inside a element using xDocument

Tags: c#, xml

This is the XML file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This file is generated by the program.-->
<DATABASE>
  <SCENE SCENE_NAME="SCENE_TestSene"></SCENE>
  </SCENE>
</DATABASE>
```

I want to write inside the Element   "SCENE SCENE_NAME="SCENE_TestSene""

This is the code where i am writing to the element.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Database.xml");
 XElement root = new XElement("XYZ");
 root.Add(new XElement("tName", "VIRAT"));
 doc.Element("//DATABASE/SCENE[@SCENE_NAME='SCENE_TestSene']").Add(root); // this line crashes the application
 doc.Save("Database.xml");
```

How can i insert the data inside the  element.

This is how it should look like after writing.

```
<DATABASE>
      <SCENE SCENE_NAME="SCENE_TestSene">
        <XYZ>
          <tName>virat</tName>
        </XYZ>
      </SCENE>
</DATABASE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `doc.XPathSelectElement("/DATABASE/SCENE[@SCENE_NAME='SCENE_TestSene']").Add(new XElement("XYZ"),new XElement("tName", "VIRAT")))`.

Comment: is it possible to add XElement("XYZ") first and in next line add XElement("tName", "VIRAT")

Comment: The main part of the answer is to use `XPathSelectElement`. As for adding multiple elements to an elements, I think the constructors in LINQ to XML allow e.g `new XElement("XYZ", new XElement("tName", "VIRAT"), new XElement("foo", "bar"))` as the constructor is declared as `public XElement (System.Xml.Linq.XName name, params object[] content);`.

Comment: i may need to add multiple elements inside XElement("XYZ") , the number may vary

Comment: Well, the constructor declares `params object[] content` so you can throw any number of arguments in there, i.e. any number of `XNode`s